# Land mine game using only switch statement ...error occuring,,,,?

Tags: c++

Look at this ...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7PD5969hho
( it's a helium ion :P( strangely enough)  I need suggestions about how to incorporate 2 electrons without making the code hyper long)

I want the dots to be removed as well.
http://www.2shared.com/document/RbqXfIdH/Helium_ion_XD.html (this is my c++ code)

The code below also has a problem... I'm having problems with switch statement

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
   int i=1,t=0,live=3;
   char choice=' ';
   char b1='a';
   char b2='b';
   char b3='c';
   char b4='d';
   char b5='e';
   char b6='f';
   char b7='g';
   char b8='h';
   char b9='i';
   char b10='j';

   clear:
   switch (choice)
   case 'a':
      b1='*';
      live--;
      break;
   case 'b':
      b2='-';
      t++;
      break;
   case 'c':
      b3='*';
      live--;
      break;
   case 'd':
      b4='-';t++;
      break;
   case 'e':
      b5='-';t++;
      break;
   case 'f':
      b6='-';t++;
      break;
   case 'g':
      b7='-';t++;
      break;
   case 'h':
      b8='*';
      live--;
      break;
   case 'i':
      b9='-';t++;
      break;
   case 'j':
      b10='-';t++;
      break;
   ///////////////////////////BOX////////…
   cout<<setw(20)<<'|'<<setw(10)<<'|'<<se…
   cout<<setw(15)<<b1<<setw(5)<<'|'<<setw(5…
   cout<<setw(20)<<'|'<<setw(10)<<'|'<<setw…
   cout<<setw(20)<<'|'<<setw(10)<<'|'<<setw…
   cout<<setw(60)<<"---------------------…
   //////////////////////////////////////…
   cout<<setw(20)<<'|'<<setw(10)<<'|'<<se…
   cout<<setw(15)<<b6<<setw(5)<<'|'<<setw(5…
   cout<<setw(20)<<'|'<<setw(10)<<'|'<<setw…
   cout<<setw(20)<<'|'<<setw(10)<<'|'<<setw…
   cout<<setw(60)<<"---------------------…

   /////////////////////////////////box end/////////////////////////////////////…
   //////////////start////////////////
   cout<<setw(40)<<"THIS GRID CONTAINS 8 BOMBS...CHOOSE 15 NUMBERS WITHOUT hittng a landmine";  
   { 
      cout<<"YOUR "<<live <<"LIVES REMAIN"<<endl;
      cout<<"ENTER YOUR"<< i << "NUMBER :";
      i++;
      cin>>choice;
      if(t==15)
      {
         cout<<"YOU WIN";
         goto end;
      };
      if(live==0)
         cout<<"YOU LOSE";

      goto clear;};
   if(live==0)
      cout<<"YOU LOSE";
   end:
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `goto clear;};` Oh god.. why?

Comment: Is the problem with the `switch` is that it is not compiling? There is no `{}` for the `switch`: `switch (choice) { case 'a': ... }`

Comment: does it even build? Where is the end of the `switch` statement? why not using loops? Why process the user input _before_ you get that input?

Comment: cmon guys...... i asked the same question on yahoo answer and i have recieved the answer...

Comment: by the way Joachim Pileborg and all you guys  it does work......http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MELTgBxjVvc&context=C38bdd33ADOEgsToPDskKUYwzhtsQOHHI_zJyr1WVG

Comment: @amit The code in the link has a gem: `goto here;` :-P

Comment: @amit can you explain what to do amit??

Comment: If you asked the question elsewhere and have received the answer, why post here too??

Comment: @amit: Well, there are extremely rare situations when it makes sense to use goto. This isn't one of them.

Comment: @Yashashavi Ym: "it does work" works or not, it is quite horrible. You need more practice before even considering posting anything even on youtube. For a start you could learn how to use arrays. If you already received an answer, you don't need to ask the question in another place.

Answer (score 2):

My first impressions from the video you supplied is that you need some form of simple graphics library to output what you're trying to do. Outputting "pseudo-graphics" within a console is just going to get increasingly messy and confusing to manage. Look into [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/), for instance.

To address the second section of your question, for one, your switch statement needs curly brackets to encapsulate its body. Indentation and formatting practices will help you identify these issues quickly and independently, so it would be a good idea to get into a habit of using these.

As a side note, I'd suggest you avoid using goto statements in your code, they quickly become unmanageable when a project grows. Maybe it would be a good idea to revise your C/C++.

Comment: i know that sir....i m planning to learn opengl...i took this as a challenge you can check my other videos as well.....they well feel less crazy and messy :P

Comment: OK sure - just thought you mightn't be fully aware of a graphics library as a viable alternative. ASCII graphics can look nice if pulled off correctly too - but organising your code WILL help regardless! ;)

Comment: @Yashashavi Ym - Dont take this the wrong way but the jump from something like this to openGL is like the grand canyon. you need to increase your knowledge of C++ and then maybe start on a small graphics library like OpenSceneGraph. Its a very good Gl for someone trying to do basic stuff and to learn. I only say this because if you look at just a small 3D project in openGl and you'll notice stuff you've never dreamed of.